# Force C to readin stdin as binary using MINGW

Tags: c, windows, mingw, std, stdin

So, I have a use case where I need to force a C program cross compiled to Windows to read in stdin as a binary format. This works great for Windows compilers, but unfortunately I am compiling this program using MinGW so I can't get access to setting the mode of the stdin as this is a pre-MSDOS, preUNIX convention. How would I force this to occur while still compiling this code in GCC? Any ideas?

The statements at fault are the following:

```
__setmode(__fileno(stdin), O_BINARY);
__setmode(__fileno(stdout), O_BINARY);
```

Comment: It should be `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);` (only one underscore) and ensure you've included all required headers.

Comment: The included headers which are? I thought the issue was that I did not have the required header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements above are not related to the compiler but to the header files and C library you are linking to.

MinGW uses the Microsoft runtime library and compatible header files.  You probably have an incorrect spelling for these functions, try removing some of the `_`, grep for `setmode` in the header files, etc:

```
grep -r setmode /usr/include
grep -r O_BINARY /usr/include
```

If you cannot find these, copy the prototypes and `#define` from the microsoft headers.

cremno suggested this:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
```

If you **really** cannot find these symbols, try this:

```
extern int _setmode(int, int);
_setmode(0, 0x8000);
_setmode(1, 0x8000);
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: as far as I know, Microsoft no longer provide headers for `msvcrt.dll` which is the runtime MinGW uses.  So if the MinGW headers don't contain the function you're looking for, and you can't find third party headers, the only option is reverse engineering or trial and error.

Comment: `_setmode(0, 0x8000)` is, frankly incomprehensible, not to mention error prone; (how do you know that `_O_BINARY` will always be expressed as `0x8000`?)  The correct formulation is to include _all_ of `<stdio.h>`, `<io.h>`, and `<fcntl.h>`, and then use `_setmode (STDIN_FILENO, _O_BINARY);` and `_setmode (STDOUT_FILENO, _O_BINARY)`, (and maybe also `_setmode (STDERR_FILENO, _O_BINARY)`).

Comment: @Keith Marshall: of course it is incomprehensible.  It is a last resort attempt in absence of actual macro and function definitions for this bogus API.  `0` and `1` are the standard low level file handles for standard input and output, `O_BINARY` used to be `0x8000` in the DOS world, it may have changed for 32 or 64 bit MSVC runtime libraries, anybody with access to the proper header files please confirm.

Comment: @chqrlie: Yes, I understood your point. Mine is that, if you are using MinGW, you _definitely_ have the appropriate header files; you should use them, and then you've no reason to write incomprehensible code, nor to care what the actual values of the appropriate manifest constants might be, no matter if they are conventionally standardized or implementation specific.